# Echo a value from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a .js file with only javascript in it and my question is; I have separate .php file and .js file. And I want to get the value the .php file echoes/returns. How can I fix this?

I searched around and found that I could use this:

php:

```
<?php
  echo 'name';  
?>
```

js:

```
var user_name;
$.get('getId.php', function(data) {
    user_name = data;
});
// other code
```

But this didn't work. Or perhaps do I need another js lib included?
I don't get what the php file returns, its blank.

Comment: You need to encode the output from PHP in key:value pairs. Use json_encode. Then you can use data.name to access it providing your key in PHP is name.

Comment: include jQuery https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 1):

use [json_encode();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Add jquery library

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

In PHP

```
<?php
  echo json_encode(array('name'));  
?>
```

THEN

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var user_name;
        $.get('getId.php', function(data) {
            user_name = data;
        });

   });   
 </script>
```

Comment: Do I need to include a lib to use that? Because it didnt work :<

Comment: include jQuery und wrap the JS code: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: one `});` is missing ;)

Comment: Yea the thing is that I have a lot of functions in that js file and it seems like 
$.get('getId.php', function(data) {
            user_name = data;
        });
is the problem... I tried to just change user_name = "name"; and ignoring the data that get returned... but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "anyfile.php",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);

            }
        });

        return false;


}); 
</script>
```